# Problema al intentar multiplicar matrices

Tags: java

Estoy intentando multiplicar matrices de la siguiente forma, sin éxito.

```
package multiplicacionaleatoria;

import javax.swing.JOptionPane;

public class MultiplicacionAleatoria {

    public static void main(String args[]) {

        int n = Integer.parseInt(JOptionPane.showInputDialog("ingrese numero de filas de la primera matriz")); // x1

        int m = Integer.parseInt(JOptionPane.showInputDialog("ingrese numero de columnas de la primera matriz")); //x2

        int o = Integer.parseInt(JOptionPane.showInputDialog("ingrese numero de filas de la segunda  matriz")); //y1

        int p = Integer.parseInt(JOptionPane.showInputDialog("ingrese numero de columnas de la primera matriz"));//y2

        int[][] m1 = new int[n][o];
        int[][] m2 = new int[m][p];
        int[][] mR = new int[n][p];

        for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < o; j++) {
                m1[i][j] = Integer.parseInt(JOptionPane.showInputDialog("numeros de la matriz 1 "));
                Integer.parseInt(JOptionPane.showInputDialog(m1[i][j] + " "));
            }

        }

        for (int i = 0; i < m; i++) {

            for (int j = 0; j < p; j++) {
                m2[i][j] = Integer.parseInt(JOptionPane.showInputDialog("numeros de la matriz 2 "));
                Integer.parseInt(JOptionPane.showInputDialog(m2[i][j] + " "));
            }

        }

        if (p == m) {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog (null,( "La matriz resultante es: "));

            for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {

                for (int j = 0; j < p; j++) {

                    for (int h = 0; h < n; h++) {

                        mR[i][j] += m1[i][h] * m2[h][j];
                    }
                    Integer.parseInt(JOptionPane.showInputDialog(mR[i][j] + " "));
                }

            }
        } else {
          JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,("Los rangos de las matrices son incorrectos"));
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: Veo que en vez de asignar a Mr el resultado de M1*M2, incrementas usando un +=, y como no veo que inicializes Mr a 0 y no se si JAVA inicializa solo a 0... prueba a cambiar el += por un =

Comment: Hola @brayandelahoz. Bienvenido a [es.so]. Por más que el código de sobreentienda, quizás conviene [edit] la pregunta agregando una breve descripción de qué valores estás ingresando, cuál es el resultado que estás obteniendo, y cuál sería el resultado esperado. Eso ayudaría bastante a que alguien que lee tu pregunta sepa más rápido dónde buscar el error.

Comment: @ArnauCastellví ya probe cambiando el menos pero me sigue saliendo error.

Answer (score 3):

Errores detectados :

- `n` es el número de filas de la primera matriz y `m` el número de columnas; por lo que debes usar `int[][] m1 = new int[n][m];`
- Una situación similar sucede con la matriz 2.
- Para multiplicar matrices deben ser iguales las columnas de la primera matriz y las filas de la segunda. Con lo que la comprobación correcta es : `if (m == o)`
- Usar `m`, `n`, `o` y `p` como nombres de variables lleva a la confusión. Esto no es un error en sí mismo pero facilita que se comentan errores. Mejor usar nombres de variables más descriptivos.

Este es el código corregido :

```
public class MultiplicacionAleatoria {

    public static void main(String args[]) {

        int m1Filas = Integer.parseInt(JOptionPane.showInputDialog("ingrese numero de filas de la primera matriz")); // x1

        int m1Columnas = Integer.parseInt(JOptionPane.showInputDialog("ingrese numero de columnas de la primera matriz")); //x2

        int m2Filas = Integer.parseInt(JOptionPane.showInputDialog("ingrese numero de filas de la segunda  matriz")); //y1

        int m2Columnas = Integer.parseInt(JOptionPane.showInputDialog("ingrese numero de columnas de la primera matriz"));//y2

        int[][] m1 = new int[m1Filas][m1Columnas];
        int[][] m2 = new int[m2Filas][m2Columnas];
        int[][] mR = new int[m1Filas][m2Columnas];

        for (int i = 0; i < m1Filas; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < m1Columnas; j++) {
                m1[i][j] = Integer.parseInt(JOptionPane.showInputDialog(
                        "Introduzca numero matriz 1 fila=" + i + " columna=" + j ));
            }

        }

        for (int i = 0; i < m1Columnas; i++) {

            for (int j = 0; j < m2Columnas; j++) {
                m2[i][j] = Integer.parseInt(JOptionPane.showInputDialog(
                        "Introduzca numero matriz 2 fila=" + i + " columna=" +j ));
            }

        }

        if (m1Columnas == m2Filas) {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog (null,( "La matriz resultante es: "));

            for (int i = 0; i < m1Filas; i++) {

                for (int j = 0; j < m2Columnas; j++) {

                    for (int h = 0; h < m2Filas; h++) {

                        mR[i][j] += m1[i][h] * m2[h][j];
                    }
                    Integer.parseInt(JOptionPane.showInputDialog(mR[i][j] + " "));
                }

            }
        } else {
          JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,("Los rangos de las matrices son incorrectos"));
        }
    }

}
```

He quitado el segundo `showInputDialog` que hay en la introducción de datos pues pienso que no aporta nada. Y en cuanto a mostrar el resultado el interfaz que usas es muy incómodo, yo lo cambiaría, pero entiendo que eso se sale del tema de la pregunta.